# Has Google Talk implemented XEP-0079?

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

Google Talk has implemented XMPP (jabber portocol) but has it implemented XEP-0079 too?

[XEP-0079](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0079.html#conditionsactions) is an XMPP extention about "Advanced Message Processing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

We can use [XEP-0030 (Service Discovery)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html) to ask the server at talk.google.com what it features it provides.

[XEP-0079](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0079.html) specifies a `<feature>` of `http://jabber.org/protocol/amp` but, as we can see from the request/response below, the gmail.com service does not include this feature in its response.

---

```
<iq to='gmail.com' type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>
</iq>

<iq xmlns='jabber:client' from='gmail.com' type='result'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'>
    <identity category='server' type='im' name='Google Talk'/>
    <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>
    <feature var='google:jingleinfo'/>
    <feature var='google:roster'/>
    <feature var='google:nosave'/>
    <feature var='google:setting'/>
    <feature var='google:shared-status'/>
    <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/archive#otr'/>
    <feature var='google:mail:notify'/>
    <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/archive#save'/>
    <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/rosterx'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

Answer (score 1):

To amplify Christopher's answer, not only does Google not implement AMP, there are few others who do, since it doesn't solve enough of the problem.  For something hop-by-hop, consider [XEP-0198: Stream Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html), which also provides quick reconnect.